# Mysql Join multiple table fields

Tags: mysql, database, join

i have again bumped into an assignment that i have some question to, and yes i have been researching and reading, so this aint my first to look for answers.

the assignment is to get an output from several tables, meaning that a "join" is required, since the informations are scattered in different tables.

i have created the code that looks like this:

```
SELECT * FROM
order_, orderspec
WHERE order_.orderno = orderspec.orderno;

SELECT * FROM
order_, customer
WHERE order_.custno = customer.custno;

SELECT * FROM
order_, employee
WHERE order_.empno = employee.empno;

SELECT * FROM
orderspec, stock
WHERE orderspec.stockno = stock.stockno;
```

Is it possible to do all this in one query/ command?

Answer (score 0):

You may try like this:-

```
SELECT * FROM
order_, orderspec, customer, employee, stock
WHERE order_.orderno = orderspec.orderno
and order_.custno = customer.custno
and order_.empno = employee.empno
and orderspec.stockno = stock.stockno;
```

Comment: I can see the output, but i was wondering, where does it get saved? since i have to only show the order number, stock number, stock name, the unit price and total price for the order, from one customer?

Comment: @Santelices:- *where does it get saved?* I didnt get that very clearly. This is a select statement using the joins. Now if I am getting you correctly, if you want any particular column then in place of * just write the name of that column and your task will complete!